# How can I clear images from IE cache?

Tags: images, internet-explorer, browser-cache, internet-explorer-11

I am having a problem clearing the cache for IE (11) when it comes to pictures. I have a site I need to test in regards to image loading times, but no matter what I do, it seems the images stay cached somewhere.

Sure I do `Ctrl+Shift+Delete` and clear the cache with these settings

[image]

But it seems to have no effect on images, and they seem to be "remembered" by the browser.

How can I ensure that image data is deleted in IE (11)?

To clarify, I need to load the page as if it were the very first time this site has ever been seen by the browser.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the browser after clearing the cache?

Comment: @Synetech Yeah, several times.

Comment: @Synetech The thing is, I have a bug in my site that image load times are responsible for, but it only shows the very first time the site is visited. I try to load the page with Ctrl+F5, clear cache, then restart browser, but it continues to remember the images, preventing me from recreating the issue more than once on any given machine.

Comment: Maybe your ISP is caching them somewhere between your site and your computer?

Comment: I also wonder how this could be more easily done via the commandline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [CCLEANER](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)  it will clean your IE history/cache with no problems including images.  It is configurable to not clear passwords and other cookies you may want to keep.

Comment: Ha, Ha, you posted this answer just after a friend of mine made that suggestion! Good answer! And Thanks!

Comment: This totally works, btw